# Round a Value after While Loop in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

Hey with the following code I am trying to round the variable $CelNum, and since I am new to PHP I am unsure of how to do it correctly if you could help me I would appreciate it.

```
<head>
    <title>Temp Conversion</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<?
$FarNum = 0;
$CelNum = 0;

while ($FarNum <= 100)
{
$CelNum = ($FarNum - 32)*5/9;
echo "<p>$FarNum = $CelNum</p>";
$FarNum++;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What exactly are you trying to achieve, and what does the current code generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to print the Celsius values for 1F - 100F. You'll have to `round` the value of `CelNum` inside the loop for it to work properly:

```
while ($FarNum <= 100)
{
    $CelNum = round( ($FarNum - 32)*5/9 );
    echo "<p>$FarNum = $CelNum</p>";
    $FarNum++;
}
```

If you want to be more accurate, you could round it to decimal places instead:

```
$CelNum = ($FarNum - 32)*5/9;
$CelNum = round($CelNum, 2); // eg: -17.78
```

[**See it live!**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AOUOtE)

Answer (score 0):

To get the CelNum rounded, use the round function:

```
$CelNum = round(($FarNum - 32) * 5 / 9);
```

In order to find this function, I simply went to php [website](http://www.php.net) and searched for 'round'. Then I found the function [itself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

Oh, by the way, do not use <? . Prefer <?php instead:

```
<?php
```